# Perform user token check in CakePHP API routes

Tags: cakephp, rest

I'm creating an API, and I'm wondering what the best practice is to check a user token.

Here's an example of the paths I'm using and its accompanying rule:

http://www.domain.com/api/user/ede12-snip-f50b9/project/1

```
Router::connect(
    "/api/user/:token/project/:projectid/issues",
    array("action" => "issues", "controller" => "projects", "[method]" => "GET"),
    array("id" => "[0-9]+", 'pass' => array('token', 'projectid'))
);
```

This works, but then I have to check the token credentials in every action. And I don't want that.

Does anyone know of another way?

Answer (score 0):

```
This works, but then I have to check the token credentials in every action. And I don't want that.
```

If your API is stateless there is no other way.

Comment: Of course, what I meant: I'll have to add the same bit of code at the beginning of every public action function.